# Spring boot + oracle driver + No suitable driver

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, driver

My application use many datasources (postgreSQL, Sybase)
I try to add one Oracle datasource

Application.properties

```
rocbis.datasource.prd.driver.class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
rocbis.datasource.prd.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<dbname>
rocbis.datasource.prd.username=<username>
rocbis.datasource.prd.password=<password>
```

*host, dbname, username & password have been obfuscated...*

Configuration class

```
@Bean(name = "rocbisDatasourcePRD")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rocbis.datasource.prd")
public DataSource rocbisDataSourcePRD() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "rocbisJDBCTemplatePRD")
public JdbcTemplate rocbisJdbcTemplatePRD(@Qualifier("rocbisDatasourcePRD") DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

and POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>19.6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When Springboot starts I have the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance
for jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<dbname> at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>DriverDataSource.java:112)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)    
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)    
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at config.DatasourceConfiguration.rocbisJdbcTemplatePRD(DatasourceConfiguration.java:446)
at config.DatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1cdc8e91.CGLIB$rocbisJdbcTemplatePRD$59(<generated>)
at config.DatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1cdc8e91$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9002c681.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at config.DatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1cdc8e91.rocbisJdbcTemplatePRD(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 64 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver    
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:104)
            ... 79 common frames omitted
             - org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
```

> I tried :

> driver-class-name instead of driver.class-name

> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver instead of oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

---

Below configurations worked for me with Oracle

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<service>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the like below in my j2ee project. You may follow

1. I have added below lib:

   ```
    1. ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar
    2. HikariCP-3.1.0.jar
    3. slf4j.jdk14-1.6.1.jar
    4. slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
   ```

Here is the connection I have used below:

```
       Connection con = null;
    try {
       
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
       
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydb");
        config.setUsername("myuser");
        config.setPassword("mypass");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(2000);
        config.setAutoCommit(false);
        config.setMinimumIdle(100);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: Don't forget to add **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver** name